# While loop exiting before computation because of datatypes

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, type-conversion

My program specifications are as follows.
1. All four digits are different 2. The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place 3. The number is odd. 4. The sum of the digits is 27.
I left out some code of the whole program. It has a clean compile but when it runs it automatically terminates. I think the problem lies somewhere in the conversion of the datatypes.

```
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
String randomString;
boolean found = true;   

while (found)
{   

// converting to string to find position of digits and value        
randomString = String.valueOf(randomNumber);

// converting to char to transfer back to in while knowing the position of the digits 
char position0a = randomString.charAt(0);
char position1a = randomString.charAt(1);
char position2a = randomString.charAt(2);
char position3a = randomString.charAt(3);

// coverted back to int
int position0 = Character.getNumericValue(position0a);
int position1 = Character.getNumericValue(position1a);
int position2 = Character.getNumericValue(position2a);
int position3 = Character.getNumericValue(position3a);

int sumCheck = position0a + position1a + position2a + position3a;
int digit30Check = 3 * position2;

//checking addition to 27
String sumCheck27 = "27";
String sumCheck28 = String.valueOf(sumCheck);

// checking all digits are different
if (position0 != position1 && position0 != position2 && position0 != position3  &&

position1 != position2 && position1 != position3 && position2 != position3) 
{
if (position3 != digit30Check) // check if the digit in the thousands place 3 * tens
{
    if (sumCheck27.equals(sumCheck28)) // check if the sum is 27
    {
        if (position0 != 1 && position0 != 3 
&& position0 != 5 && position0 != 7 &&      
position0 != 9 && position1 != 1 && position1 != 3 
&& position1 != 5 && position1 != 7 && 
position1 != 9 && position2 != 2 && position2 != 3 
&& position2 != 5 && position2 != 7 && 
position2 != 9 && position3 != 3 && position3 != 3 && 
position3 != 5 && position3 != 7 && position3 != 9)
        { 
// checks for odd digits
         found = false;
         System.out.println(randomNumber);

        }
        else 
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
    }
    else 
    randomNumber = rand.nextInt(9000) + 1000;               
}
else 
randomNumber = rand.nextInt(9000) + 1000; 
}
else 
 randomNumber = rand.nextInt(9000) + 1000; 

 // end while
 }
```

Comment: Among the answers below, i would like to give out a little pointer to when determining if the number in position 0 is odd, you can simply do: ((position0%2)==0)  [which will return true if it is even and false if it is odd]. Same goes for the rest of the position variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boolean found = false;  

while (found)
```

This alone ensures the while loop will never be entered, since `found` is false. Anything inside the while loop doesn't make any difference, since it will never be executed.

You probably meant to write

```
while (!found)
```

Beside this error, your conditions are over complicated. Here's how you can simplify them :

```
if ((position0 == (3 * position2)) && // note that position0 is the "thousands place", not position3
    ((position0+position1+position2+position3) == 27) && // sum of digits
    (position3 % 2 == 1) && // odd number
    (position0 != position1 && position0 != position2 && position0 != position3  &&
     position1 != position2 && position1 != position3 && position2 != position3)) { // different digits
    found = true;
}
```

Comment: I just changed that and I still have the bug. Thanks for the help, can't believe i missed that small one.

Comment: @Lunian See my edit. You conditions are too complicated, so it's hard to spot your bug. I suggesst to replace them with my simpler condition.

Comment: I agree, I should have simplified them to where they were more easily executed and debugged. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Swap `while(found)` for `while(!found)`.

Just think about it logically. You don't want to look while you've found something. You want to keep looking while you've not found it.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks! I still have the bug however.

Comment: Do you see anything printed before the program exits?

Comment: Nothing. The program runs endlessly.

Comment: Then your conditional logic needs attention!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be simplified significantly by looking at the given inequalities, soemthing like

```
// thousands + hundreds + tens + ones == 27
// thousands = tens * 3, or tens = thousands / 3
// thousands = 3, 6 or 9
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // thousands = tens * 3; so it must be a multiple of 3.
    for (int thousands = 3; thousands < 10; thousands += 3) {
        for (int hundreds = 0; hundreds < 10; hundreds++) {
            if (hundreds == thousands) {
                continue;
            }
            // thousands = tens * 3; so the reverse is also true
            int tens = thousands / 3;
            if (tens == hundreds) {
                continue;
            }
            // All of the digits sum to 27.
            int ones = 27 - thousands - hundreds - tens;
            if (ones > 9 || ones % 2 != 0 || ones == tens
                    || ones == hundreds || ones == thousands) {
                continue;
            }
            int val = (thousands * 1000) + (hundreds * 100) + (tens * 10)
                    + ones;
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the output is still

```
9738
```